# Counterexample for the Picard Lindelöf Theorem without hypothesis of continuity.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I am considering the following version of the theorem:

**Picard–Lindelöf theorem:** Consider the initial value problem
$$x'=F(t,x) \quad x(t_0) =x_0.$$
Suppose  that $F$  is locally Lipschitz in x (meaning the Lipschitz constant can be taken independent of t) and continuous in t, then for some value $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a unique solution $y(t)$ to the initial value problem on the interval $[t_{0}-\varepsilon ,t_{0}+\varepsilon]$.

If the function is not locally Lipschitz in x, I know some counterexamples.

My question is for when the function is not continuous. I thought of something like

$$x'=\frac{2}{t}x \quad x(0) =1.$$

But that way the function at least is defined at zero. Is there any example where the function is not continuous and has two solutions or where the function is defined in sentences? I can't conclude whether that would be possible.

Thank for your help!

Comment: not sure if useful - if $x$ solves the ODE, then $F(t,x)$, being equal to a (classical) derivative $x'$, must satisfy the intermediate value property (in t).

Comment: Your initial point is not part of the domain of the DE, at $t=0$ there is an unavoidable singularity in the equation. The solution formula $x(t)=ct^2$ also does not allow the value $x(0)=1$ in an extension or limit sense. So your example is not a counter example, as P-L does not make any claims for the behavior of solutions when crossing to the outside of the (open) domain.

Comment: I agree with you. I'm right when it isn't continuous what happens.

Comment: If take the equation $tx'=2x$ with $x(0)=1$ would this problem occur too?